# Как подключить JavaFx к Maven?

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Фрагмент из pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>start/Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Main-класс

```
package start;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConnectToDataBases connect = new ConnectToDataBases();
 new Main().buildGui();
}
public void buildGui(){
    Stage stage = new Stage();
}

}
```

Исключение

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at javafx.stage.Window.<init>(Window.java:1209)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:239)
at javafx.stage.Stage.<init>(Stage.java:227)
at start.Main.buildGui(Main.java:12)
at start.Main.main(Main.java:9)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This operation is permitted on 
the event thread only; currentThread = main
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.checkEventThread(Application.java:443)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.setEventHandler(Screen.java:285)
atcom.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.setScreenConfigurationListener(QuantumToolkit.java:674)
at javafx.stage.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:79)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Могу ошибиться, но кажется сталкивался с такой проблемой в ScalaFx, что суть есть Scala обертка над JavaFx. Там это лечилось тем, что Main класс надо было унаследовать от JFXApp(В джаве класс может носить другое имя). Проверьте пейперы на предмет этой догадки. Как я сказал, может быть я не прав, но все же лучше чем ничего, верно? =)

Comment: Хех, заработало! Не пойму, каким боком, как но работает..